# Is there a way to shift the screen 20 rows, but keep the cursor in the same position?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to move the screen 20 rows but keep the cursor in the same position in Vim? For example if the cursor is near the top of the screen, and I'd like to read something 15 lines above the cursor, (I believe) I have to type 15k and then 15j to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd><C-E></kbd> and <kbd><C-Y></kbd> scroll the screen, so <kbd>20<C-Y></kbd> will do it.

You could also use <kbd>zt</kbd> and <kbd>zb</kbd> to scroll until the cursor is at the top or bottom of the screen.